# Не работает правило ACL на запись

Tags: linux, debian, acl

Изучаю ACL, соответственно создал файл в определённом каталоге и стал экспериментировать с правилами с помощью *setfacl*. Заметил такую вещь, что если пользователь (допустим user1) не владелец файла и не root, то даже если ему выдали соответствующие права на запись через *setfacl*, то user1 данный файл всё равно редактировать не сможет.

Далее продемонстрирую это.

1. Создаю файла *file* в директории */tmp* и проверяю права на файл *file* и каталог */tmp* и для чистоты эксперимента удаляю права на чтение этого файла всем кроме владельца:

   ```
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$
   /tmp
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ touch file
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ chmod go-r file
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ getfacl file
   # file: file
   # owner: jonni
   # group: jonni
   user::rw-
   group::---
   other::---

   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ getfacl /tmp
   getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
   # file: tmp
   # owner: root
   # group: root
   # flags: --t
   user::rwx
   group::rwx
   other::rwx
   ```
2. Далее для пользователя user1 (пользователь user1 состоит только в группе user1, которая создалась по умолчанию при создании данного пользователя с помощью утилиты useradd) пропишу права read, write, execute на файл file:

   ```
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ setfacl -m u:user1:rwx file
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ getfacl file
   # file: file
   # owner: jonni
   # group: jonni
   user::rw-
   user:user1:rwx
   group::---
   mask::rwx
   other::---
   ```
3. Проверим, что владелец файл может совершать операции read, write, но не execute:

   ```
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ echo "echo inform">>file
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ cat file
   echo inform
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ ./file
   -bash: ./file: Permission denied
   ```

   Всё, как и следовало ожидать, работает корректно.
4. А вот в случае user1 начинаются проблемы. Проверим, что все операции выполняются корректно:

   ```
   jonni@Debian:/tmp$ su user1
   Password: 
   user1@Debian:/tmp$ cat file
   echo inform
   user1@Debian:/tmp$ ./file
   inform
   user1@Debian:/tmp$ echo text>>file
   bash: file: Permission denied
   ```

В данном случае все операции, кроме write выполнились корректно. Ума не приложу почему нет возможности редактировать файл за пользователя user1.
Прошу подсказать по этому вопросу. Спасибо.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: При переносе файла в другой каталог всё работает — значит что-то не так конкретно с `/tmp`, возможно мешается sticky bit

Comment: @andreymal, спасибо, и правда, sticky bit ограничивал возможность записи в файл.
Я не придал ему значение, так как считал, что skicky bit просто ограничивает возможность удаления файлов (но не записи в них), принадлежащих другому пользователю.